# He who must not be named? (aka Anyone can ping everyone in chat)

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, ping

For some or other reason, typing `@ᔕᖺᘎᕊ` in a chat room pings everyone who's been in that chat room for the last 7 days...

Seems to work in all chat rooms (I only tested 2 as I don't want to upset too many people...)

*How should we proceed?*

Comment: I can confirm this

Comment: Yes. Balpha wanted to kill everyone and freeze the tavern

Comment: [Balpha knows about it.](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4003450#4003450)

Comment: As a side note: searching google for `ᔕᖺᘎᕊ` is an amazing way to find sites that duplicate (legally or illegally) SO content, since @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ posts a lot but otherwise those characters don't really get used for anything.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[image: screenshot of SSMS showing N'foo' like N'ᔕᖺᘎᕊ%' being true]

That is all.

Comment: LOL. Talk about lazy programming :D

Comment: That is evil. How did you fix it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Switch to a binary collation. Apparently SQL Server tries to be really smart when comparing strings even though ***I'd just like to compare two strings thank you very much***. Credit for the quick fix goes to Nick Craver by the way who knew immediately why SQL Server was behaving like this.

Comment: So, it's Microsoft's fault? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can get onboard with that placement of blame.

Comment: I'm conflicted.  The answer demonstrates [a bad thing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232(v=sql.80).aspx), and therefore should be downvoted, but it also explains [the root of the problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PkLUJ.jpg), so it should be upvoted.

Comment: but wait... why has this only started happening now? Did something else change in chat recently that triggered it?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Hmm that's a great question. I had assumed that your name was new, but apparently that's not the case. We'll look a bit closer.

Comment: lol no - I've had it for a few (6?) months now... Please do update me if you ever find out why it happened :) Thanks!

Comment: For posterity's sake, why was it doing that then?

Comment: So, was it because the collation used didn't have any sort order for canadian syllabics? (If so, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226851/how-do-locales-work-in-linux-posix-and-what-transformations-are-applied)

Comment: Can someone explain this?

Comment: lol - seems like this will remain a mystery forever...? :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ for ever ever... ;)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ nobody pinged you before, duh. :-)