# Is "The Stack Exchange Network" room really haunted?

Tags: support, bug, chat, notifications, ping

I've been told that [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11254/the-stack-exchange-network) is haunted, but I didn't really believe it until I heard a ping (while I was in the room and another), looked everywhere, but couldn't find its origin... This happened yesterday, and today there is still no sign of any ping in my notifications inbox, so am I dealing with a real ghost here, is this just a bug that I hear a ping when nobody has pinged me, or is there another explanation for this?

**TL;DR:**

I heard the ping sound, but I have checked, and I was not pinged, there is not other notification of the ping as there usually would be if I had been pinged, no sign of an edited or deleted message that pinged me, nor any notification later on in my notifications inbox. So where did the ping come from?

Comment: Told by whom? And my pc goes beep all the time...

Comment: Spooooooooky...

Comment: Undaunted by death, I'm going to enter that room now. If I don't ever come back, tell my wife and kids (if I had any...) that I love them!

Comment: @rene: Everyone in that room knows, that's basically the only thing spoken about in that room...

Comment: Community has achieved consciousness. *THE PING IS COMING FROM INSIDE THE ROOM!*

Comment: Well, you've been pinged two times yesterday, and responded to both. Did you have any other pings?

Comment: @nicael: No... And it definitely wasn't one of those... I heard a third ping... And even if they just edited their message it normally still gives me that little circle on the right of my picture to show me that I have been pinged...

Comment: And I didn't get anything...

Comment: I definitely heard the noise, but nobody pinged me at that time... I received a disembodied ping!

Comment: Hm. Probably needs a poem.

Comment: @nicael: It already has one! ByteCommander wrote one [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25533171#25533171)! :D

Comment: It's not spooktober anymore.

Comment: Hallucinations happen all the time.

Comment: @bjb568: I have a good mental history, so I doubt that it would be anything like that... More likely to be a cyber-ghost!

Comment: Hallucinations happen to all of us, haven't you ever heard or even felt your phone buzzing when it wasn't?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266830/he-who-must-not-be-named-aka-anyone-can-ping-everyone-in-chat) bug? Somehow you got the remains from the past?