# Why does @Oɹʇɥo ping @Ortho?

Tags: bug, chat, ping

My understanding was that if the first three characters of a name match a username present in the chat for the previous seven days, the person will be pinged.

Out of curiosity, why does @Oɹʇ ping @Ortho? Aren't they different characters?

[image]

This seems to only happen in @Ortho's case.  [Flipping @Snail and @Cowp](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35838590#35838590) doesn't have the same effect.

---

**Edit:** It seems replacing any username that contains "r" with "ɹ", or "t" with "ʇ" works. You can probably reproduce this with some "user1234" accounts, if they've visited your chat.

Comment: I guess the code is replacing/ignoring certain characters, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266830/he-who-must-not-be-named-aka-anyone-can-ping-everyone-in-chat).